# Showing info when clicking on specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm a Dutch boy with my own website and i'm kind of new to all the programming. I know the little basic HTML, but my knowledge stops there. Now I wanted to create something on my page where I offer some services for the computer and more.

So on the left I want to have all my services listed and on the right the info for that service. I don't want all info just on the right, I want it to appear and disappear when you click a service on the same page. When no service is clicked, I want to have a text with some explanation about the services and more. I want the possibility to change the info and add images and some HTML plugins. I think this is possible with HTML5 (or Javascript, maybe jQuery) only I don't know how.

This is where I want to test it: http://webguideict.com/test/ 
My website is running on Wordpress and might be slow because of the hoster I have (BlueHost), I'm doing it on my own and they were very cheap, now I know why.

Are there programmers that can and want to help me with my problem? Preferably with some pre-written code or just very simple explained, I love to learn!

Thanks in advance! 
Thomas

Comment: I would recommend picking up a book or two, or you could even read through [this site](http://learn.jquery.com) and see where you get. But stack overflow isn't a free coder service. You need to put in some effort, and we'll help when you get stuck or have a specific question.

Comment: http://css-plus.com/2011/08/create-accordions-with-css3-html5-and-jquery/

Comment: See revisions to my answer, to respond to your specific question. One or two more things to add, so will edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific question sounds like it is mostly jQuery/javascript.

<kbd>[See this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tBUgF/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<h2>Services:</h2>
<ul>
    <li id="con">
        Consulting
    </li>
    <li id="pro">
        Programming
    </li>
    <li id="brd">
        Longboarding
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var svc = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(svc);

    if (svc=="con"){
        $('#msg').html('<h2>Professional Services</h2>I can help with computer consulting.');
    }else if(svc=="pro"){
        $('#msg').html('<h2>Beanie Work</h2>If you can conceive it, I can code it.');
    }else if(svc=="brd"){
        $('#msg').html('<h2>Sidewalk Surfing</h2>Grocery deliveries with style...');
    }
});
```

---

Thomas, there are many great sites with free tutorials for doing all the stuff you want.

I recommend doing at least some of these (free) 10-minute tutorials, and probably even all of them if you really want to learn. They are a good place to start:

[phpAcademy.org](http://phpacademy.org/)
[thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11)
[200 ten-minute jQuery tuts](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)
[Register & Login tutorial](https://phpacademy.org/course/register-login)

This is an invaluable resource for consulting/memorizing jquery selectors/methods:

[jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)
[jQuery Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp)
*Just keep hitting `Next Chapter` and it will take you through six more pages...  Print and store in the little reading room down the hall...*

Comment: I edited my answer above. The specific language you need is jQuery (a javascript library). I recommend going straight to jQ, as it does almost everything you need to do in js, and as you expand your advanced knowledge you will start to pick up js as you go. Doing it the other way around (js first) adds 3x the time/effort, IMHO.

Comment: You sir, are awesome, this is really the thing I needed, a good hit in the right direction and a nice example, I will learn and try to understand everything you typed to make it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got started was using the website http://www.codecademy.com/ and then getting involved on this site once I got up and running. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm already a member from CodeCademy, only the problem is my free time. I'm a student and I don't have much spare time, I wanted to make this to make my website a bit better again. Can you please tell me what language I should learn to solve this problem and in which direction I have to think? That should help me a lot!

Comment: Um, learn, CSS HTML5 and Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Yes, Web Fundamentals will be a great start: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web Get going with that, I believe it will be the quickest way of getting you up to speed. When I got stuck in on codecademy, I quickly got addicted and was designing a site in a week. Another great website for testing stuff out is jsfiddle.net, which is a really quick way of trying out ideas.